# Get videos from Vimeo channel using AJAX without jQuery

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest, jsonp, vimeo

I'm trying to write a simple AJAX method to get a list of videos from Vimeo without using jQuery. I realize that I must use the JSONP format because it is a cross-domain request. However, the result returned is always 200 OK and it is always empty. Here's my method:

```
var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();

httpRequest.open("GET", "http://vimeo.com/api/v2/channel/staffpicks/videos.json?callback=?", true);
httpRequest.send();

httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (httpRequest.readyState == 0) {
        console.log("0");
    }
    if (httpRequest.readyState == 1) {
        console.log("1");
    }
    if (httpRequest.readyState == 2) {
        console.log("2");
    }
    if (httpRequest.readyState == 3) {
        console.log("3");
    }
    if (httpRequest.readyState == 4 && httpRequest.status == 200) {
        console.log("4");
    }
    if (httpRequest.readyState == 4 && httpRequest.status == 404) {
        console.log("5");
    }
};
```

The console logs 2, but not 0, 1, 3, 4, or 5. It's always just 2.

By the way, this doesn't have to be a Vimeo request. The only reason I'm using a Vimeo URL is because I don't know how else to test an AJAX request than to hit an actual site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In retrospect, this is a pretty poor question. It's really two or three questions:

1. Why does my cross-domain request to Vimeo return 200 OK but it is empty?
2. Why does the console log 2 but not 0, 1, 3, 4, or 5?
3. How else can I test an AJAX request other than to hit an actual site?

The answers to questions one and two are below, posted by Alexander and Eswar Rajesh Pinapala, respectively. The answer to question three is to request a local JavaScript file.

One thing I struggled with that others might benefit from is that httpRequest.status throws an exception when httpRequest.readyState is 0 or 1. So this doesn't work:

```
httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function () {
    alert(httpRequest.readyState + httpRequest.status);
};​
```

Here is what worked for me:

```
try {
    httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    console.log("0");

    httpRequest.open(options.method, options.url, true);
    console.log("1");

    httpRequest.send();
} catch (err) {
    console.log(err.name + ': ' + err.message + ' (line ' + err.lineNumber + ')');

    return false;
}

httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (httpRequest.status === 404) {
        this.onreadystatechange = null;

        return false;
    }

    if (httpRequest.readyState === 2) {
        console.log("2");
    } else if (httpRequest.readyState === 3) {
        console.log("3");
    } else if (httpRequest.readyState === 4) {
        console.log("4");

        return true;
    }
};
```

The reason for wrapping the constructor, open, and send methods in a try...catch statement is so you can catch any errors that result from a bad filename or something. These will blow up before it ever gets into the onreadystatechange function. The onreadystatechange property is only initialized once the send method has been called.

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand what these numbers mean.

The readyState property indicates the current state of the request. It returns a 4-byte integer.

This property is read-only and has the following defined values

```
UNINITIALIZED(0) 
The object has been created, but has not been initialized (the open method has not been called).
LOADING(1) 
The object has been created but the send method has not been called.
LOADED(2) 
The send method has been called and the status and headers are available, but the response is not.
INTERACTIVE(3) 
some data has been received. You can get the partial results using the responseBody and the responseText properties.
COMPLETED(4) 
All the data has been received, and is available.
```

try

```
httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function () {
    alert(httpRequest.readyState + httpRequest.status);

};​
```

for status:

200 Status OK
400 HTTP Error 400 Bad request

ans then decide on what you receive fromt he server.

Comment: This explains why the console doesn't log 0 or 1 because I'm calling the open and send methods before I ever check to see if the ready state has changed. When would the console log 3? Would that be some kind of error? Also, status is always null. Any idea why?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use JSONP you need to do it differently, or the [Cross Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/http_access_control) is not going to let the request through.

```
// Define a callback function
var log = function(videos){
  console.log(videos);
};

// Get the JSONP response and insert it in your DOM
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = "http://vimeo.com/api/v2/channel/staffpicks/videos.json?callback=log";
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
```

Usually with a JSON request you get:

```
[ { id: 0, title: "this is a title" } ]
```

​
But, when you send a JSONP request you get the response wrapped around your provided callback function:

```
log([ { id: 0, title: "this is a title" } ])
```

At the moment you insert this response into your DOM your callback function can do its job (a simple function call from Javacript.)

This is the [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/DGq4e/).

Comment: This explains why I'm not getting any data back from Vimeo. The method I'm writing needs to work for any AJAX request, so I guess I need to have a separate method if it is a cross-domain request.